# related rows mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I need to select 5 rows from a table related to a new row just added.

I work on a web site of advertisements when a user publishes a new advertisement i would like to link 5 advertisements related to this advertisement.

The criteria is to search list of words (extracted from the title of new advertisement just added) in the titles of the others advertisement stored on the database.

it's a kind to use regular expression in MySQL to verify multiple requirements in the single advertisement title.

can someone help me to build MySQL query to get this result

eg :

title of the new advertisement : "selling new android smartphone"
extracted worlds : "android" and "smartphone"

some advertisements :

1 - "search to bye new smartphone"

2 - "selling android product"

3 - "new smartphone"

4 - "good selling car"

6 - ",nwx wxclkn wxc "

the query should return the ids of the 1,2,3 advertisement.

Comment: Also, your post could use a lot more clarification. It is hard to tell what you are asking.

Comment: You want us to help you reinvent Google AdWords?  Here's a hint: I'm pretty sure they don't use MySQL *or* regexes.  But I'm reasonably certain the Web is involved somehow.

Comment: @JohnFx not at all to reinvent Google AdWords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your answers

i foun d a solution to do this without adding tags to ads just i ha ve to extracte needed words from the new added add and then create mysql regular expression like

extracted words : "android" "smartphone"

SQL :

`SELECT * FROM ad_table WHERE title REGEXP '[[:<:]]android[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]smartphone[[:>:]]'`

Comment: What about synonyms? `cellphone` and `phone` and `smarthphone`. And also, for instance, `Android` may be considered related to `iPhone`. You really need some tag system if you want this to work, you don't have enough words in an ad title to rely on that. Plus, the `REGEXP` option is way slower...

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing would be to have tags associated with each ad, so that then you can associate ads through the tags themselves. You cannot just rely on the titles as, for instance "selling cellphones" would be related to your example even if it does not have any word in common.

You would then retrieve the tags associated to an ad and look for other ads with the same tags, ordering the results by the number of matching tags.